# How to deploy properly filter driver to target machine?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, wdk, filter-driver

I cannot find out from the windows documentation how to deploy filter driver properly. I know that filter driver is different from device driver as is said [here](http://www.easefilter.com/Forums_Files/Introduction_To_File_System_Filter_Drivers.htm) and It cannot control any  hardware I/O device, but it has to be installed some way.

**My Environment:**

```
 - Visual Studio 2015
 - WDK 10
 - VirtualBox with Windows 10
 - Windows 10
```

**Steps I have done**:

1. Create default mini filter driver project
2. Added a driver package to project.
3. for package Configuration Properties -> Driver Install -> Deployment set Target device.
4. step 5 or 6
5. If I set "Do no Install" [as someone tell here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779530/installing-file-system-minifilter-from-inf-launched-from-debug)
   I cannot observe any debug message.
6. If I set "Install/Reinstall and verify" there is error:

   `WDTF_TEST : System has no device the driver package can be installed onto`

I found that it could be probably loaded by 'fltmc' tool, but I want to deploy and debug the driver on the second machine, by caling Visual Studio 'Run' function. How it could be achieved in Visual Studio?

Comment: So the main question is how to debug filter driver from host pc in such a way that the DbgPrint gives the logs and It will be run from visual studio driecly

Comment: I have run "fltmc load FsFilter1.sys" so the FsFilter is visible in fltmc log, next I break the kernel, and tried load symbols  (.sympath, .symfix, .reload)  and execute !dbgprint -> "dbgprint buffer is empty" so it does not work. I have also tried !wdfkd.wdflogdump FsFilter1.sys but it says that "It looks like wdm driver"... I searching through documentation but I do not find any tips. I could not imagine that microsoft driver developing has that high learning curve. Any tips or links how to debug filter driver will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand how to do so. It has to be set "Do not install" -> and only way to debug it is to 1) set break point in visual studio (ex. in DeviceEntry)  2) Run KernelDebugger from VS  3) on target set "fltmc load FsFilter1" 4) in debugger immediate windows "!dbgprint" will show commands, If someone has better alternative please share

Comment: 1) set break point in visual studio (ex. in DeviceEntry)  2) Run KernelDebugger from VS  3) break all in VS 4) set !dbgprint  in in debugger immediate window 5) you should install inf file C:\DriverTest\drivers right-click  install. 6) fltmc unload FsFilter if loaded 7) on target set "fltmc load FsFilter1", 8) you are at break point.